# Unable to work out why a parameter to a method is corrupt in Release mode but OK in Debug mode

Tags: c++, mfc

Here is a method:

```
// Override to be notified about every file processed
bool MultiActionsNext(LPCTSTR lpszFileInZip = NULL)
{
    if (CZipActionCallback::MultiActionsNext())
    {
        CMultiActionsInfo* pMulti = GetMultiActionsInfo();
        CString strProgress, strPercentComplete;

        strPercentComplete.Format(_T("%d%%"),
            theApp.CalculatePercent(pMulti->m_uFilesProcessed, pMulti->m_uTotalFilesToProcess));

        if (lpszFileInZip != NULL)
        {
            strProgress = lpszFileInZip;
        }
        else
        {
            strProgress.Format(_T("Files Processed: %u of %u"),
                pMulti->m_uFilesProcessed, pMulti->m_uTotalFilesToProcess);
        }

        if (m_pWndProgressText != nullptr)
        {
            m_pWndProgressText->SetWindowText(strProgress);
            m_pWndProgressText->UpdateWindow();
        }
        if (m_pWndProgressPercentText != nullptr)
        {
            m_pWndProgressPercentText->SetWindowText(strPercentComplete);
            m_pWndProgressPercentText->UpdateWindow();
        }
        if (m_pProgressCtrl != nullptr)
            m_pProgressCtrl->SetPos(pMulti->m_uFilesProcessed);
        return true;
    }
    else
        // Processing was requested to be stopped.
        // It won't happen in this sample code, because
        // the Callback method always returns true.
        return false;
}
```

My problem is with this line of code:

```
m_pWndProgressText->SetWindowText(strProgress);
```

If I am in **DEBUG** mode the result is fine:

[image: Debug build]

But when I am in **RELEASE** mode the result is garbage:

[image: Release build]

If I put a break point in this function for `lpszFileInZip`:

- Debug:

[image: Debug Break Point]

- Release:

[image: Release Break Point]

I can't work out why one is OK and one is not.

---

In Release 32 bit mode I do now notice that I get an exception that indicates the passed in parameter is not valid:

[image: Release Break Point 32 Bit]

Comment: Somewhere, somehow, you are mixing a module built in ANSI mode with one built in Unicode mode. The two modules don't agree on the meaning of `LPCTSTR`. Check how you build that third-party library you are using; I suspect the settings differ between Debug and Release.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you. I had compiled the wrong libraries in the ZipArchive project. I needed the MD ones and not the MT ones. Now it is OK. Thanks.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Do you want to convert that comment into an answer?